# Call public member with **ClassObject ( C++ )

Tags: c++

I need to call my public member. The Constructor that takes 1 paramater.

This is how my code looks:
// main

```
char tmpArray[100] = {};

while ( !inFile.eof() )
{
   for ( unsigned x = 0; x < str2.length(); x++ )
   {
    if ( !isspace( str2[x] ) || isspace( str2[x] ) ) 
    {   
       tmpArray[x] = str2[x]; // prepare to supply the constructor with each word
       ClassObject[wrdCount] = new ClassType[x] ;
       //ClassObject[wordCount]->ClassType( tmpArray );
    }
   }
}
```

The error is:

> 'function-style cast' : illegal as
>   right side of '->' operator

To try and resolve the issue i try two equivalent expressions:

```
/* no good */ (*ClassObject[wrdCount]).ClassType( tmpArray );
/* no good */ (*ClassObject[wrdCount][10]).ClassType( tmpArray );
/* combine */ ClassObject[arbitrary][values]->ClassType( tmpArray );
```

Intellisense does brings up all my members and privates except the constructor..
Could this be the reason?

//MyHeader.h

```
class ClassObject
{
    private:
    const char* cPtr;
    float theLength;
public:
    ClassObject( const char* );  // Yes its here and saved..
    ClassObject(); // an appropriate default constructor
    ~ClassObject( );
    char GetThis( );
    char* GetThat( );
}
```

Comment: Can you post the whole code for this? I don't understand how you have a ClassObject class and are also using ClassObject as a pointer.

Comment: Am I missing something or is the line "if ( !isspace( str2[x] ) || isspace( str2[x] ) )" always going to evaluate to true?

Comment: Its really not clear what you are asking.
Are you trying to count the occurences of each word?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the following things as it is not clear from the code posted:

(1). ClassObject is defined like this: ClassType* ClassObject[/*some value*/10];

(2). The class definition in MyHeader.h is of ClassType and not of ClassObject.

In such a case, the following statement is the problem:

```
ClassObject[wrdCount] = new ClassType[x]
```

Here it creates 'x' number of ClassType objects. I don't think thats what you want. I guess you want to construct a ClassType object by passing const char* as the constructor parameter. If that is so you should use it like this:

```
ClassObject[wrdCount] = new ClassType(tmpAray);
```

Also note that you are assuming size of the array passed. I suggest it is better to use something like a std::string instead of raw character arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're doing, but you cannot explicitly call a constructor like that. If you have a pointer-to-a-pointer-to-a-`ClassType` called `ClassObject`, you need to do something like this to initialize it:

```
ClassObject[wrdCount] = new ClassType*[x]; // create a new 'row' in the array with x columns
for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i) // initialize each 'column' in the new row
    ClassObject[wrdCount][i] = new ClassType(tmpArray);
```

This doesn't seem to make much sense given the code you have pasted though (since wrdCount doesn't change). It's hard to say without an exact problem description.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use identifiers. The following:

```
ClassObject[wrdCount] = new ClassType[x] ;
```

tries to apply the `operator[]` to a class type name. What good can that do? None. Try:

```
ClassObject *a = new ClassType[x];
```

This'd create an object `a` of type array of size `x` of `Classtype`s. Do you need an array here -- it's upto you. If all you need is a single variable use:

```
ClassObject *a = new ClassType;
```

Comment: Yes, but this was before ClassObject was defined by the OP, and for some reason (I cannot recall now) I had a hunch that this is a typedef for a class pointer. Duh! I'll update.